# Implement upsert with where condition in HBase

Tags: database, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm using HBase and I need to run an upsert but it doesn't works, any ideas?

Example:

```
UPSERT INTO TABLE_A (status) VALUES('Finished') WHERE ID = 3943;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of research I found the solution:

```
UPSERT INTO TABLE_A (id, status) SELECT ID,  'Finished' AS STATUS  FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID = 3945;
```

I hope I can help someone with my same problem